# Is there way to use NSParagraphStyle.default.mutableCopy() without force unwraping?

Tags: ios, swift, unwrap

I m trying to get an instance of `NSParagraphStyle.default.mutableCopy()` but are we sure that `mutableCopy()` will always contain a value?

```
var paragraphStyle = NSParagraphStyle.default.mutableCopy() as! NSMutableParagraphStyle
```

Would it possible to do this without force unwraping?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, it's much simpler:

```
let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle() // Note the `let`
```

You get the `default` parameters with the *default* initializer.

---

Apart from that in this case you *can be sure that `mutableCopy()` will always contain a value* because `NSParagraphStyle` clearly conforms to `NSCopying`.

Comment: Thanks for your reactivity